# CMS Connect(HTML)

Tags: community

I'm trying to connect to a Drupal built web site in order to use the page from the website on my salesforce community. Every time I create a connection and  try it in the community builder it says (HTTP returned with code 0) [image]

My connection looks like this : [image]

Can you tell me how to do it on drupal based site, my error seems to not have it's solution on google. 
Thank you

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find the reason? Was it related to CORS?